# Query two xml files with javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I am working on a project and am struggling given the restrictions. I would normally handle this sort of thing with PHP but the project needs to run on a server that is limited, I need to accomplish this entirely with javascript.

Script as follows:

1 - Load XML File 1, find the "id" of the node that has the playState child equal to "Running" (there will be only be one).

2 - Using the id, load XML file 2, and return the name of the timeline whose ID matches the value from step 1.

I am completely stumped, I've tried using jquery selectors but can't get a handle on how to actually search for and return one specific value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

XML File 1:

```
<response>
  <timelineStatus id = "1">
    <playState>Idle</playState>
    <position>P00H00M00.00S</position>
    <onStage>false</onStage>
  </timelineStatus>
  <timelineStatus id = "101">
    <playState>Idle</playState>
    <position>P00H00M00.00S</position>
    <onStage>false</onStage>
  </timelineStatus>
  <timelineStatus id = "102">
    <playState>Running</playState>
    <position>P00H00M00.00S</position>
    <onStage>false</onStage>
  </timelineStatus>
  <timelineStatus id = "103">
    <playState>Idle</playState>
    <position>P00H00M00.00S</position>
    <onStage>false</onStage>
  </timelineStatus>
  <timelineStatus id = "104">
    <playState>Idle</playState>
    <position>P00H00M00.00S</position>
    <onStage>false</onStage>
  </timelineStatus>
......
```

XML File 2:

```
<response>
  <timeline id = "1">
    <name>System - Custom Color Base</name>
    <length>P00H00M10.00S</length>
    <timeSource>
      <type>Internal</type>
    </timeSource>
    <timeOffset>P00H00M00.00S</timeOffset>
  </timeline>
  <timeline id = "101">
    <name>Preset - Red</name>
    <length>P00H00M00.00S</length>
    <timeSource>
      <type>Internal</type>
    </timeSource>
    <timeOffset>P00H00M00.00S</timeOffset>
  </timeline>
  <timeline id = "102">
    <name>Preset - Green</name>
    <length>P00H00M00.00S</length>
    <timeSource>
      <type>Internal</type>
    </timeSource>
    <timeOffset>P00H00M00.00S</timeOffset>
  </timeline>
  <timeline id = "103">
    <name>Preset - Blue</name>
    <length>P00H00M00.00S</length>
    <timeSource>
      <type>Internal</type>
    </timeSource>
    <timeOffset>P00H00M00.00S</timeOffset>
  </timeline>
  <timeline id = "104">
    <name>Preset - Magenta</name>
    <length>P00H00M00.00S</length>
    <timeSource>
      <type>Internal</type>
    </timeSource>
    <timeOffset>P00H00M00.00S</timeOffset>
  </timeline>
......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full details of your solution with JavaScript.

**xml1.xml**

As you shown above

**xml2.xml**

As you shown above

**Solution:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function getOutput(){
                var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr1.open("GET", "xml1.xml", false);
                xhr1.send(null);
                xml1 = (xhr1.responseXML);

                var xPathRes = xml1.evaluate("//timelineStatus/playState", xml1, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE , null);
                result = new Array();
                var res = xPathRes.iterateNext();

                while (res) {                   
                    var playState = res.textContent;
                    if(playState == "Running")
                    {
                        resParentNode = res.parentNode;
                        var timelinstStatusId = resParentNode.getAttribute("id"); //id="102"

                        var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr2.open("GET", "xml2.xml", false);
                        xhr2.send(null);
                        xml2 = (xhr2.responseXML);
                        console.log(xml2);

                        var xPathRes2 = xml2.evaluate("//timeline[@id='"+timelinstStatusId+"']/name", xml2, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE , null);
                        result = xPathRes2.singleNodeValue;
                                            console.log(result.textContent); //Preset - Green
                        return result.textContent; //Preset - Green
                        break;
                    }
                    //Iterate through set of Results
                    res = xPathRes.iterateNext();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getOutput();">getOutput</a>
</body>
</html>
```